# Strange frame in Windows 8 app taskbar icon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a weird gray frame in taskbar icon of my Windows 8 application (please, see http://postimg.org/image/oprig8dh3/).
Does anyone know how can I get rid of it?

p.s. I have Logo.scale-100.png, SmallLogo.scale-100.png, SplashScreen.scale-100.png, StoreLogo.scale-100.png in Assets folder of my Windows 8  project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the XAML?

Comment: What is your background color set to?

Comment: Filip, you are right. It was gray. I have appointed blue background to splashscreen but not to Tile.
If you formalize your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't think that changing the background is the real solution, because I see that other apps have icons which fill the whole of the area which includes the "strange frame". I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: @StephenHosking did you found the solution? I have same problem. In windows 10 such style called "unplated" icon, and it looks like there's no way to do it on windows 8/8.1 (